# How to alphabetically sort coma separated cells Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, compare, delimiter, flatten

Please see below the project I'm trying to solve and for which I need your help.

| (E) Choice-not sorted | (F) Choice-sorted |
| --- | --- |
| Banana, Orange, Apple | Apple, Banana, Orange |
| Strawberry, Orange | Orange, Strawberry |
| Coffee, Apple, Strawberry, Lime, Shoes | Apple, Coffee, Lime, Shoes, Strawberry |
| Etc. | Etc. |

How to get F from E?

I found some solutions in stackoverflow but for some reasons, I didn't manage to make them work.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pivot it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A5)&"", REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A5)&"♦♣"&SPLIT(A1:A5, ",")&","), "♣")), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 <>',' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), ",$", ), 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: `ROW(A2:A5)&""` to convert to text?

Comment: @Osm yes indeed